IndexedDB getting flushed on Android webview with ungraceful shutdown
I have a cordova based Android application that runs web based content and used localstorage and indexedDB. I am encountering an issue where if the Android device is powered OFF and powered ON multiple times by pulling out power cable, it results in indexedDB getting flushed which contains crucial information to run the application which I dont want to get deleted.
I tried monitoring indexedDB size and found that it doesn't reach to its capacity (only 10-15% occupied). On checking adb logs found some errors related to db:
07-12 16:36:05.933  1427  2388 E chromium: [ERROR:leveldb_factory.cc(88)] Failed to open LevelDB database from /data/user/0/player/app_webview/Default/IndexedDB/file__0.indexeddb.leveldb,Corruption: missing start of fragmented record(2)
07-12 16:36:05.933  1427  2388 E chromium: [ERROR:indexed_db_factory.cc(732)] Got corruption for { origin: file:// [internally: file://], top-level site: file://, nonce: <null>, ancestor chain bit: Same-Site }, missing start of fragmented record
07-12 16:36:05.947  1427  2388 E chromium: [ERROR:indexed_db_factory.cc(889)] IndexedDB recovering from a corrupted (and deleted) database.
07-12 16:36:06.109  1427  1427 D CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/firmware.html)

Is there any configuration or settings needed for cordova so that this could be avoided?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

What do you mean by "the Android device is powered OFF and powered ON multiple times by pulling out power cable" ? The device has no battery ?

Yes, I am dealing with Advantech devices (https://www.advantech.com/en-us/products/a4d5fede-290b-4141-8ab9-1d15f013606a/usm-110c/mod_6981db9d-2f01-4a26-8964-3bb58f107b99). They operate with power cable and there are cases when staff pull out power cable instead of shutting down with button on the devices.

Then this is a user mistake! You can't fix this... It's like saying, the data wasn't saved to the hard drive because the end user pulled the power cord from the computer. You can't fix stupid.

@Eric I understand that. I am looking for potential workarounds or solutions that other Android apps acquire to handle these cases.

There is no work around a user pulling the power cord...

Thanks Eric for your response. This issue is also surfaced in case of power outage as well. So if there is power outage and power recovery, then the application is in weird state (with indexedDB flushed off).
Is there any recommendation/practices that people follow to avoid this.

You should sync the indexedDB every time your app is started. The master data should be on your server and you should flush indexedDB at every start and populate it with the master data coming from the backend.
